# Strange output of Bash for (assoc array)

Tags: bash, associative-array, bash4

I have this array:

```
declare -A modeAndAction
modeAndAction[category]=create
modeAndAction[attribute]=create
modeAndAction[customers]=create
modeAndAction[newsletter]=create
modeAndAction[vouchers]=create
modeAndAction[products]=create
modeAndAction[orders]=create
```

Which outputs this:

```
Starting import of mode : attribute
With action: create
Starting import of mode : category
With action: create
Starting import of mode : newsletter
With action: create
Starting import of mode : vouchers
With action: create
Starting import of mode : orders
With action: create
Starting import of mode : customers
With action: create
Starting import of mode : products
With action: create
```

But I expect this output:

```
Starting import of mode : category
With action: create
Starting import of mode : attribute
With action: create
Starting import of mode : customer
With action: create
Starting import of mode : newsletter
With action: create
Starting import of mode : vouchers
With action: create
Starting import of mode : products
With action: create
Starting import of mode : orders
With action: create
```

So everything moved in the output, ignoring its declartion, but I dont understand why.
I want the modes (+ its action) to be called exactly in the order I have the array declared in.

Bash Version:

```
GNU bash, version 4.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

//Edit
I found out that if I have this array

```
modeAndAction[AAAAAAAAA]=create;
modeAndAction[B]=create;
modeAndAction[C]=create;
modeAndAction[D]=create;
```

I get this output:

```
Starting import of mode : B
With action: create
Starting import of mode : C
With action: create
Starting import of mode : D
With action: create
Starting import of mode : AAAAAAAAA
With action: create
```

So it auto-sorts it by key lenght.

//Edit2
Code for responsible for the output

```
for i in "${!modeAndAction[@]}"
    do
        echo "Starting import of mode : $i"
        echo "With action: ${modeAndAction[$i]}"
    done
```

Comment: Associative arrays don't *have* an "order". Also you didn't show the code used to generate the output.

Comment: Your first sample output indicates that key length is not the issue. The issue is almost certainly that traversal order is unspecified.

Comment: @EtanReisner I have added the code responsible for the output.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by using non assoc array keys now:

```
    modeAndAction[0]=category
    modeAndAction[1]=attribute
    modeAndAction[2]=customers
    modeAndAction[3]=newsletter
    modeAndAction[4]=vouchers
    modeAndAction[5]=products
    modeAndAction[6]=orders


    for i in "${!modeAndAction[@]}"
    do
        echo "Starting import of mode : ${modeAndAction[$i]} with action create"
        # ...
    done
```

Comment: An equivalent way to declare that array: `modeAndAction=(category attribute customers newsletter vouchers products orders)`